# Nodejs : Kineticjs in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I install the package Kineticjs in nodejs and have the following error message:

```html
Kinetic.window = Kinetic.document.createWindow();
                                              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /kinetic/kinetic.js:608:47
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.createWindow`was removed from jsdom 1.0.0-pre.1. Use jsdom 0.11.1 with kinetic

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems like that, you can always read on documentation. also

```
console.log(typeof Kinetic.document.createWindow);
```

Also if u do not have access to source code or u can not simply find it. u can always output javascript code via simply reading it with simple I/O

```
http://serebrov.github.io/html/2013-12-02-node-core-module-source.html
```

here is example

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('fs.js', fs.toString());
fs.writeFileSync('fs.readFileSync.js', fs.readFileSync.toString());
```

this will copy the source code of fs to new js file that u can read.